Having issues in unit test cases regarding unsupported types
I have a below code implemented for functionality is as below:
GetBandsRangeMapping - Joins BandsRange and BandsMappings to form BandsRangeMappings and stores into cache to fetch result frequently
GetPredictionsFromJsonAsync - Fetches result in correct json format
GetBandsPredictions - return Predictions
I am having issues in Unit Tests where it shows and I am trying to run the test cases and get results
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....FindAll()
Non-overridable members (here: RepositoryBase.FindAll) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
public async Task <List<BandsRangeMappings>> GetBandsRangeMapping() {
  try {
    // Step 1: Check if the BandsRangeMappings are already cached
    if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out List < BandsRangeMappings > ? cachedBandRangeMappings)) {
      // Step 2: If not cached, retrieve the data from the database
      var bandsRange = await _unitOfWork.BandsRangeRepository.FindAll().ToListAsync();
      var bandMappings = await _unitOfWork.BandsMappingsRepository.FindAll().ToListAsync();

      // Step 3: Join BandsRange and BandsMappings to form BandsRangeMappings
      cachedBandRangeMappings = (from br in bandsRange join bm in bandMappings on br.Band equals bm.Band select new PriceBandsRangeMappings {
        Category = br.Category, // "A", "B"
          CountryCode = br.CountryCode, // 'Sweden"
          Band = br.Band, // 1,2,3,4,5
          BandName = bm.BandName, // "A", "B", "C"
          Range = br.Range // "$450.00 - $679.99"
      }).ToList();

      // Step 4: Store the result in the cache with expiration options
      var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
        .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(12)) // Cache expires 12 hours after the last access
        .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(24)); // Absolute expiration after 24 hours

      _memoryCache.Set(cacheKey, cachedBandRangeMappings, cacheEntryOptions);
    }

    // Step 5: Return the cached (or newly fetched) data : Return empty list if null
    return (cachedBandRangeMappings != null ? cachedBandRangeMappings : new List < BandsRangeMappings > ());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    _logger.LogError(ex, "Error");
    throw;
  }
}

public async Task < List < BandsPredictionsResult >> GetPredictionsFromJsonAsync(string userId, string countryCode, string jsonString) {
  List < BandsPredictionsResult > bandsMappingResult = new List < BandsPredictionsResult > ();

  try {
    JsonElement root = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString).RootElement;

    // Iterate through each property in the JSON object
    foreach(JsonProperty category in root.EnumerateObject()) {
      var currentCategory = new BandsPredictionsResult();
      currentCategory.UserId = userId;
      currentCategory.Category = category.Name;
      currentCategory.CountryCode = countryCode;
      currentCategory.BandsDetailsList = new List < BandsDetails > ();

      JsonElement values = category.Value;

      // Ensure the value is an array
      if (values.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array) {
        // Iterate through each integer in the array
        foreach(JsonElement value in values.EnumerateArray()) {
          var bandDetails = new BandsDetails();

          // Fetch the band range mappings (using GetBandsRangeMapping)
          var bandMappings = await GetBandsRangeMapping();

          var result = bandMappings.Where(bm => bm.Category.Equals(category.Name) && bm.CountryCode.Equals(countryCode) && bm.Band == value.GetInt32()).ToList().First();
          bandDetails.Band = result.Band;
          bandDetails.BandName = result.BandName;
          bandDetails.Range = result.Range;

          currentCategory.BandsDetailsList.Add(bandDetails);
        }
      }
      bandsMappingResult.Add(currentCategory);
    }

    return bandsMappingResult;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    _logger.LogError(ex, "Error");
    throw;
  }
}

public List < BandsPredictionsResult > GetBandsPredictions(string userId, string countryCode) {
  try {
    var result = _unitOfWork.BandsPredictionsRepository.FindByCondition(x => x.UserId.Equals(userId) && x.CountryCode.Equals(countryCode)).First();
    List < BandsPredictionsResult > bandsResults = new List < BandsPredictionsResult > ();

    if (result == null) {
      throw new HttpRequestException($"No Bands found for id: {userId}", null, HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    } else {
      bandsResults = GetPredictionsFromJsonAsync(userId, countryCode, result.Predictions).Result.ToList();
    }
    return bandsResults;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    _logger.LogError(ex, $ "Error");
    throw;
  }
}

[Table("bands_predictions", Schema = "abc")]
public class BandsPredictions {
  [Key]
  [Column("user_id")]
  public required string UserId {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Key]
  [Column("country_code")]
  public required string CountryCode {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Column("predictions", TypeName = "jsonb")]
  public string Predictions {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Column("last_updated")]
  public DateTime LastUpdated {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

[Table("category_bands", Schema = "bands")]
public class BandsRange {
  [Key]
  [Column("category")]
  public required string Category {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Key]
  [Column("country_code")]
  public required string CountryCode {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Column("band")]
  public int Band {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Column("range")]
  public required string Range {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Column("last_updated")]
  public DateTime LastUpdated {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

[Table("bands_mappings", Schema = "bands")]
public class BandsMappings {
  [Key]
  [Column("band")]
  public int Band {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Column("band_name")]
  public required string BandName {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Column("last_updated")]
  public DateTime LastUpdated {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
public class BandsRangeMappings {
  public string Category {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string CountryCode {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public int Band {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string BandName {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Range {
    get;
    set;
  }

}
public class BandsPredictionsResult {
  public string UserId {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Category {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string CountryCode {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public List < BandsDetails > BandsDetailsList {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class BandsDetails {
  public int Band {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string BandName {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Range {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork {
  BandsPredictionsRepository BandsPredictionsRepository {
    get;
  }
  BandsMappingsRepository BandsMappingsRepository {
    get;
  }
  BandsRangeRepository BandsRangeRepository {
    get;
  }

  public class BandsPredictionsRepository: RepositoryBase < BandsPredictions > , IRepository < BandsPredictions > {
    public BandsPredictionsRepository(PostgresDBContext context): base(context) {}

  }

  public class BandsMappingsRepository: RepositoryBase < BandsMappings > , IRepository < BandsMappings > {
    public BandsMappingsRepository(PostgresDBContext context): base(context) {}

  }
  public class BandsRangeRepository: RepositoryBase < BandsRange > , IRepository < BandsRange > {
    public BandsRangeRepository(PostgresDBContext context): base(context) {}

  }



  public class PostgresDBQueriesTest {
    private readonly Mock < IUnitOfWork > _unitOfWork;
    private readonly Mock < IMemoryCache > _memoryCache;
    private readonly Mock < ILogger < PostgresDBQueries >> _logger;
    private readonly PostgresDBQueries _postDBQueries;

    public PostgresDBQueriesTest() {
      _unitOfWork = new Mock < IUnitOfWork > ();
      _memoryCache = new Mock < IMemoryCache > ();
      _logger = new Mock < ILogger < PostgresDBQueries >> ();
      _postDBQueries = new PostgresDBQueries(_logger.Object, _unitOfWork.Object, _memoryCache.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetPredictionsFromJsonAsync_ReturnsMappedResults() {
      // Arrange
      string userId = "1";
      string countryCode = "Sweden";
      string jsonString = "{ \"A\": [5, 4], \"B\": [5, 3]}";
      var bandRangeMappings = new List < BandsRangeMappings > {
        new BandsRangeMappings {
          Category = "A", CountryCode = "Sweden", Band = 4, BandName = "High", Range = "$800 - $900"
        },
        new BandsRangeMappings {
          Category = "A", CountryCode = "Sweden", Band = 5, BandName = "Very High", Range = "$1400 - $10000"
        },
        new BandsRangeMappings {
          Category = "B", CountryCode = "Sweden", Band = 3, BandName = "Medium", Range = "$900 - $1100"
        },
        new BandsRangeMappings {
          Category = "B", CountryCode = "Sweden", Band = 5, BandName = "Very High", Range = "$1500 - $10000"
        },
      };

      _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.BandsRangeRepository.FindAll()).Returns(new List < BandsRange > ().AsQueryable());
      _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.BandsMappingsRepository.FindAll()).Returns(new List < BandsMappings > ().AsQueryable());
      _memoryCache.Setup(m => m.TryGetValue(It.IsAny < string > (), out bandRangeMappings)).Returns(true);

      // Act
      var result = await _postDBQueries.GetPredictionsFromJsonAsync(userId, countryCode, jsonString);

      // Assert
      Assert.NotNull(result);
      Assert.Equal(2, result.Count); // Should return two categories
      Assert.Equal(2, result[0].BandsDetailsList.Count); // Category A should have 2 bands
      Assert.Equal(2, result[1].BandsDetailsList.Count); // Category B should have 2 bands
    }

    [Fact]
    public void GetBandsPredictions_ReturnsPredictions() {
      // Arrange
      string userId = "1";
      string countryCode = "Sweden";
      var bandPrediction = new BandsPredictions {
        UserId = userId,
          CountryCode = countryCode,
          Predictions = "{ \"A\": [5, 4], \"B\": [5, 3]}"
      };

      _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.BandsPredictionsRepository.FindByCondition(It.IsAny < Func < BandsPredictions, bool >> ()))
        .Returns(new List < BandsPredictions > {
          bandPrediction
        }.AsQueryable());

      _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.BandsRangeRepository.FindAll()).Returns(new List < BandsRange > ().AsQueryable());
      _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.BandsMappingsRepository.FindAll()).Returns(new List < BandsMappings > ().AsQueryable());

      // Act
      var result = _postDBQueries.GetBandsPredictions(userId, countryCode);

      // Assert
      Assert.NotNull(result);
      Assert.Equal(2, result.Count); // Should return two categories
      Assert.Equal(2, result[0].BandsDetailsList.Count); // Category A should have 2 bands
      Assert.Equal(2, result[1].BandsDetailsList.Count); // Category B should have 2 bands
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetBandsRangeMapping_ReturnsFromCache_WhenAvailable() {
      // Arrange
      var mockCacheKey = "MockBandsRangeMappingsCache";
      var cachedMappings = new List < BandsRangeMappings > {
        new BandsRangeMappings {
          Category = "A", CountryCode = "Sweden", Band = 1, BandName = "Very Low", Range = "$0 - $400"
        }
      };

      _memoryCache.Setup(m => m.TryGetValue(mockCacheKey, out cachedMappings)).Returns(true);

      // Act
      var result = await _postDBQueries.GetBandsRangeMapping();

      // Assert
      Assert.NotNull(result);
      Assert.Equal("A", result[0].Category);
      Assert.Equal("Sweden", result[0].CountryCode);
      Assert.Equal(1, result[0].Band);
      Assert.Equal("Very Low", result[0].BandName);
      Assert.Equal("$0 - $400", result[0].Range);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetBandsRangeMapping_FetchesFromDatabase_WhenNotCached() {
      // Arrange
      var cacheKey = "MockBandsRangeMappingsCache";
      var bandsRange = new List < BandsRange > {
        new BandsRange {
          Category = "A", CountryCode = "Sweden", Band = 2, PriceRange = "$450 - $680"
        }
      };
      var bandMappings = new List < BandsMappings > {
        new BandsMappings {
          Band = 2, BandName = "Low"
        }
      };

      _memoryCache.Setup(m => m.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out It.Ref < List < BandsRangeMappings >> .IsAny)).Returns(false);
      _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.BandsRangeRepository.FindAll()).Returns(bandsRange.AsQueryable());
      _unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.BandsMappingsRepository.FindAll()).Returns(bandMappings.AsQueryable());

      // Act
      var result = await _postDBQueries.GetBandsRangeMapping();

      // Assert
      Assert.NotNull(result);
      Assert.Equal("A", result[0].Category);
      Assert.Equal("Sweden", result[0].CountryCode);
      Assert.Equal(2, result[0].Band);
      Assert.Equal("Low", result[0].BandName);
      Assert.Equal("$450 - $680", result[0].Range);

      // Verify that the cache was set
      _memoryCache.Verify(m => m.Set(cacheKey, It.IsAny < List < BandsRangeMappings >> (), It.IsAny < MemoryCacheEntryOptions > ()), Times.Once);
    }




Please reduce your code to a [mre]
